# C++ UniquePtr Implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, pointers

Took a shot at implementing `std::unique_ptr`.

Code:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
struct DefaultDeleter {
    void operator()(T* ptr) const  {
        delete ptr;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct DefaultDeleter<T[]> {
    void operator()(T* ptr) const {
        delete[] ptr;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Deleter = DefaultDeleter<T>>
class UniquePtr {
public:
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;
    using deleter_type = Deleter;

    constexpr UniquePtr() noexcept : m_ptr{nullptr} {}
    explicit UniquePtr (pointer p) noexcept : m_ptr{p} {}
    explicit UniquePtr (pointer p, const deleter_type& deleter) :
        m_ptr{p}, 
        m_deleter{deleter} 
    {}

    UniquePtr(const UniquePtr& other) = delete;
    UniquePtr& operator=(const UniquePtr& other) = delete; 

    UniquePtr(UniquePtr&& other) noexcept :
        m_ptr{other.release()}, 
        m_deleter{std::move(other.m_deleter)} 
    {}

    // Added this to allow for runtime polymorphism, but I didn't 
    // see such a constructor on cppreference. Am I just missing something
    // or should this be handled another way? 
    template<typename U, 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>, bool> = false>
    UniquePtr(UniquePtr<U>&& other) noexcept :
        m_ptr{other.release()} 
    {}

    UniquePtr& operator=(UniquePtr&& other) noexcept {
        if (this != &other) {
            m_deleter(m_ptr);
            m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
            other.m_ptr = nullptr;
            m_deleter = std::move(other.m_deleter);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    pointer release() noexcept {
        pointer result = m_ptr;
        m_ptr = nullptr;
        return result;
    }

    void reset(pointer ptr = pointer()) noexcept {
        pointer old_ptr = m_ptr;
        m_ptr = ptr;
        if (old_ptr) {
            m_deleter(old_ptr);
        }
    }

    void swap(UniquePtr& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(m_ptr, other.ptr_);
        std::swap(m_deleter, other.m_deleter);
    }

    pointer get() const noexcept {
        return m_ptr;
    }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return get() != nullptr;
    }

    std::add_lvalue_reference_t<element_type> operator* () const 
        noexcept(noexcept(*std::declval<pointer>())) {
        return *m_ptr;
    }

    pointer operator->() const noexcept {
        return m_ptr;
    }

    ~UniquePtr() {
        m_deleter(m_ptr);
    }
private:
    pointer m_ptr;
    deleter_type m_deleter;
};


template<typename T, typename... Args>
UniquePtr<T> makeUnique(Args&&... args) {
    return UniquePtr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Some tests, mostly attempting to show the example functionality on cppreference.com works with my implementation. Plus a couple extra tests to fill in gaps/test things a bit more precisely.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "UniquePtr.h"

/* Test setup code (adapted from cppreference.com) */

// helper class for runtime polymorphism demo below
struct B
{
    virtual ~B() = default; 
    virtual int val() const {return 0;}
};
 
struct D : B
{
    D() { }
    ~D() {}
 
    int val() const override {
        // dummy value to demonstrate dereferencing
        return 2;
    }
};
 
// a function consuming a unique_ptr can take it by value or by rvalue reference
UniquePtr<D> pass_through(UniquePtr<D> p)
{
    p->val();
    return p;
}
 
// helper function for the custom deleter demo below
void close_file(std::FILE* fp)
{
    std::fclose(fp);
}

struct Node
{
    int data;
    UniquePtr<Node> next;
};
// unique_ptr-based linked list demo
struct List
{
    UniquePtr<Node> head;
 
    ~List()
    {
        // destroy list nodes sequentially in a loop, the default destructor
        // would have invoked its `next`'s destructor recursively, which would
        // cause stack overflow for sufficiently large lists.
        while (head)
        {
            
            // std::cout << "before first move \n";
            auto next = std::move(head->next);
            // std::cout << "before second move \n";
            head = std::move(next);
        }
    }
 
    void push(int data)
    {
        head = UniquePtr<Node>(new Node{data, std::move(head)});
    }
};

/* Beginning of tests */

void testOwnershipTransfer() {
    UniquePtr<D> p = makeUnique<D>();
    UniquePtr<D> q = pass_through(std::move(p));
    assert(!p);
}

void testNullUniquePtr() {
    UniquePtr<D> p;
} // this function should exit successfully 

void testDererference() {
    UniquePtr<D> p = makeUnique<D>();
    D obj = *p;
    assert(obj.val() == 2);
}

void testBool() {
    UniquePtr<D> p;
    assert(!p);

    p = makeUnique<D>();
    assert(p);

    p.reset();
    assert(!p);
}

void testRuntimePolymorphism() {
    UniquePtr<B> p = makeUnique<D>();
    assert(p -> val() == 2);  
}

void testFileDeletion() {
    std::ofstream("test.txt") << 'x'; // prepare the file to read
    {
        using unique_file_t = UniquePtr<std::FILE, decltype(&close_file)>;
        unique_file_t fp(std::fopen("test.txt", "r"), &close_file);
        if (fp) {
            assert(char(std::fgetc(fp.get())) == 'x');
        }
    } // `close_file()` called here (if `fp` is not null)
}

void testExceptionSafety() {
    try
    {
        UniquePtr<D, void(*)(D*)> p(new D, [](D* ptr)
        {
            delete ptr;
        });
 
        throw std::runtime_error(""); // `p` would leak here if it were a plain pointer
    }
    catch (const std::exception&) { std::cout << "Caught exception\n"; }
}

void testLinkedList() {
    List wall;
    for (int i = 0; i != 1'000'000; ++i)
        wall.push(i);
} // function should exit successfully 


int main()
{
    testOwnershipTransfer();
    testNullUniquePtr();
    testDererference();
    testBool();
    testRuntimePolymorphism();
    testFileDeletion();
    testExceptionSafety();
    testLinkedList();
}
```

This omits the array specialization, because when taking a peek at the GCC implementation it seems to be mostly a duplication of the class with some variations here and there to support arrays. Is this how it needs to be done, or is it possible to reuse the existing code somehow and write a small, concise class for the array specialization?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can take a look!

Answer (score 1):

The converting constructor you added is part of the interface of `std::unique_ptr`. It is number (6) of the list on cppreference. However you should change yours to also accept `UniquePtr`'s with a different deleter. But you have to be somewhat pedantic to exhibit the required behaviour if `Deleter` is a reference type.

```
// To access private members of UniquePtr's with different template parameters
template <typename, typename> friend class UniquePtr;

// Converting constructors
// Version 1 for non-reference deleter types
template<typename U, typename E,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>, bool> = false,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference_v<Deleter> && std::is_convertible_v<E, Deleter>,
                     bool> = false>
UniquePtr(UniquePtr<U, E>&& other) noexcept :
    m_ptr{other.release()}, m_deleter{std::move(other.m_deleter)} {}

// Converting constructors
// Version 2 for reference deleter types
template<typename U, typename E,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>, bool> = false,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference_v<Deleter> && std::is_same_v<E, Deleter>,
                     bool> = false>
UniquePtr(UniquePtr<U, E>&& other) noexcept :
    m_ptr{other.release()}, m_deleter{other.m_deleter} {}
```

However for the new converting constructors to work, we need to specify a conversion for the different deleter types involved:

```
DefaultDeleter() = default;
    
template <typename U,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>, bool> = true>
DefaultDeleter(DefaultDeleter<U> const&) {}
```

---

Probably most of the time `Deleter` will be `DefaultDeleter<T>`. `DefaultDeleter<T>` is an empty type. But since it's a member of `UniquePtr`, C++ requires it to have a unique memory address. Because of this your `UniquePtr` will have size 16 instead of size 8 (on 64-bit systems), with the second 8 bytes being wasted space. To solve this, you could add the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute. Unfortunately, microsofts C++ compiler does not honour this attribute. Another solution is to exploit empty base class optimization, which all major C++ compilers support. Make a private base class of `UniquePtr`, that has the deleter as a member or as a base class, depending on whether `Deleter` is a class type or not.

```
template <typename Deleter, bool = std::is_class_v<Deleter> && !std::is_final_v<Deleter>>
struct DeleterHolder: private Deleter {
    // Use perfect forwarding for construction with class types
    template <typename E>
    DeleterHolder(E&& e): Deleter(std::forward<E>(e)) {}

    Deleter& get_deleter() noexcept {
        return static_cast<Deleter&>(*this);
    }

    const Deleter& get_deleter() const noexcept {
        return static_cast<Deleter const&>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename Deleter>
struct DeleterHolder<Deleter, false> {
    // Simply pass pointers and references 'by value'
    DeleterHolder(Deleter d): m_deleter(d) {}

    Deleter& get_deleter() noexcept {
        return this->m_deleter;
    }

    const Deleter& get_deleter() const noexcept {
        return this->m_deleter;
    }

private:
    Deleter m_deleter;
};

template<typename T, typename Deleter = DefaultDeleter<T>>
class UniquePtr: DeleterHolder<Deleter> { 
public:
    using DeleterHolder<Deleter>::get_deleter;

    // Rest of the implementation...
};
```

Now you have to go through all the places where you use the deleter and update the code there to use `get_deleter` and the constructor of `DeleterHolder`.

We do not unconditionally inherit from `Deleter`, because it might be a function type, which you cannot inherit from.

Thanks to @Deduplicator for pointing out an issue in the previous version of the code here :-)

---

Otherwise the implementation looks fine from what I can see :-)

It is great that you added tests. But you should add more tests that directly verify that the contracts of the smart pointer are fulfilled. For example, check that objects always get deleted when the pointer goes out of scope, check that no double deletion happens etc. Also you might want to consider to use a test framework such as Catch2 or google test.

Comment: `DeleterHolder` is not empty, as it has a (though empty) member which is not a base. Still, you are on the right track for using EBO where `[[no_unique_address]]` is not honored.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for pointing this out, I hoped there was a way to do it without two implementations for class types and non-class types.

Comment: One implementation for empty non-final class types, one for the rest...

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort to review! Couple questions:

1. In the enable_if call for the non-reference deleter, you have the condition `std::is_convertible_v<E, Deleter>`, but for the reference deleter the condition is `std::is_same_v<E, Deleter>`. Why can't the reference deleter also check if the deleter is convertible? Why the tighter constraint here? 

2. Why should the non-reference version call std::move() on the deleter, but the reference version shouldn't? 

(continued in next comment)

Comment: 3. Why do we need a conversion constructor for the deleter if it's an empty type? 

4. why does the DeleterHolder specialization for classes need to inherit privately from Deleter? Is this to ensure DeleterHolder has access to it, but not UniquePtr itself?

Comment: @jdav22 1. I assume it might be to prevent accidental copies of the deleter, but I don't really know. I was just following the standard here. 2. There is no point in calling `std::move`, since argument and parameter are both the same l-value-reference type. `std::move` would cast to rvalue-reference and that be implicitly be converted to lvalue again.

Comment: 3. By requiring our deleters to be convertible, we make them sign a contract. By making `Deleter<U>` be convertible to `Deleter<T>`, the author of `Deleter` promises that `Deleter<T>` can delete pointer of type `U*` after being converted to `T*`. And the fact that `DefaultDeleter<T>` is empty does not mean that all possible deleters are empty. 4. It doesn't matter here if we inherit privately or publicly. I just did it because data hiding is generally a good habit, but in this case it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Thanks @chrysante, all makes sense! Again appreciate the help

Comment: Revisiting this a few months later, one quick note on Microsoft's compiler not supporting `[[no_unique_address]]` - we can do `[[msvc::no_unique_address]]` to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the Swap Idiom to Move Instances

Among other benefits, swaps can be thread-safe atomic operations that never throw exceptions.

#### About That Converting Constructor

(Thanks to @chrysante for pointing out a serious oversight in my original answer.)

One important piece of functionality here is the ability to do things like:

```
 std::unique_ptr<Base> foo = std::make_unique<Derived>(bar, baz);
```

You implement this with the converting constructor

```
    // Added this to allow for runtime polymorphism, but I didn't 
    // see such a constructor on cppreference. Am I just missing something
    // or should this be handled another way? 
    template<typename U, 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>, bool> = false>
    UniquePtr(UniquePtr<U>&& other) noexcept :
        m_ptr{other.release()} 
    {}
```

First, in a reinventing-the-wheel project, you get to use `requires` from C++20, which is much nicer than `std::enable_if`.  So I recommend that.

Second, this implementation will break if the pointer conversion changes the bits of the pointer, even if it is from a derived class to a base class with a `virtual` destructor.  This is because not all pointer conversions are pointer-interconvertible.  That is, some pointer conversions (such as multiple or virtual inheritance) produce a pointer with different bits.  Calling the original deleter, which expects a `T*` and not a `U*`, with the converted `U*`, would then fail.  The current approach is only safe in two cases:

- Where `std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_class<T,U>` is `true` and the destructor of `T` is either `virtual` or trivial, or
- Where `std::is_layout_compatible<T,U>`, `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>` and `std::is_trivially_destructible<U>` are all true.  (The standard does not say `std::unique_ptr` should support this case.)

At present, however, the implementation supports this for all possible conversions, including arbitrary one-way custom conversion operators.  The only way to make this work robustly would be to store the closure of the deleter and the original pointer inside each instance.

If you aren’t going to go through all that, you could declare non-pointer-interconvertible aliasing unsupported, add a check for that to your `restrict` clauses, and keep the simple, high-performance implementation you have now.  In that case, you want to declare your deleter with the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute, so that the vast majority of deleters, which are unit types whose instance contain nothing, don’t need to be created and stored as objects.

Otherwise, you could put a`/*** BIG IMPORTANT WARNING ***/` in your header file that people are only supposed to pass in a deleter that still works, somehow, with every possible conversion to a base pointer.  And then say, the bugs this causes are on them for not reading the documentation.

Finally, since you ask, the converting constructor appears to be [number 6 on Cppreference,](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) as of July 2023.

Comment: I'm confused. OP already has a converting constructor as far as I can see. And why would you go through any of the hassle with `std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of`? The standard does not require the deleter of the old `unique_ptr` to be invoked with the old value of the pointer when the new `unique_ptr` is destroyed. I.e. if `Base* q = p` has a different value than `Derived* p`, `delete q` still works fine and deletes the object as long as `Base` has a virtual destructor. Also wrapping every call to `delete` in a `std::function` can be a nightmare for performance.

Comment: @chrysante Thanks for pointing out the converting constructor. It’s defined with `std::enable_if`, which I wasn’t looking for, and I missed it. (I should correct this and suggest the use of `requires`.)

Comment: @chrysante It is, unfortunately, not the case that calling the provided deleter with `static_cast<Base*>(p)` will necessarily work. Examples where it wouldn’t include some implementations of multiple and virtual inheritance. If the base class is not pointer-interconvertible, `(Base*)p` might have different bits than `p`, which the arbitrary deleter might not recognize.

Comment: @chrysante If you don’t want to take the performance penalty of storing a `std::function` in each instance of `unique_ptr`, OP needs to restrict the conversions to types that will actually work with the implementation. That is: pointer-interconvertible base classes, and layout-compatible types.

Comment: I think `std::unique_ptr` solves this problem by requiring the deleters to be convertible. `std::unique_ptr<T, D> p = std::unique_ptr<U, E>(/*...*/);` is only valid if `U*` is convertible to `T*` and if `E` is convertible to `D`. And by allowing conversions between your different deleter types, you implicitly say: `D` can delete all pointers that `E` can delete (after being converted to the type of pointer `D` can delete). So worrying about the deleters being compatible is not the responsibility of `unique_ptr` but that of the deleters.

Comment: That is my understanding at least. If this is not correct I'd gladly be corrected :-)

Comment: @chrysante I would need to review the Standard, which I can’t do right now because I have somewhere to be, to see what the language-lawyer take on this is. My imperfect recollection is, `std::unique_ptr` just says that the conversion-from  `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` to `std::unique_ptr<Base>` is allowed, but not necessarily for every specialization of deleter type.

Comment: I just checked libc++'s implementation of `unique_ptr` and its converting constructor and it doesn't perform any of the checks you suggest. I know that pointer conversions from derived to base can change the _value_ of the pointer, even in a way that cannot be known at compile time, if virtual inheritance is involved. But that is what virtual destructors are for afaik. If you have the time, I would gladly see a counter example of where the checks are necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Davislor for the time and effort to review! Couple questions:

1. Can you be more specific about why some pointer conversions may change underlying bits? And I believe this is only an issue if the deleters are specific to a given type, so the `DefaultDeleter` would work fine in this case? 

2. If there was no deleter support here, then would the implementation of the converting constructor be OK? Or is there anything else to be concerned about?